# Discovering public ip from wifi signals, shodan, parent router NAT

Tags: ip, nat, dhcp, isp, bridge

MAC addresses innately do not change right?
and you're able to scan for broadcasting APs where you'll be able to detect different nearby mac addresses of each AP..

Public IP addresses change, according to the ISP right?
obviously, private ip addresses are redundant to talk about here, so.. are you able to scan broadcasting APs for their public ip addresses?

this curiosity spurred as a result of me recently discovering SHODAN, it can obviously detect public IP addresses of not only ordinary APs but only many other things, i know how shodan works so there's no confusion here and i do not believe myself that shodan uses wireless to scan networks

so basically is it possible to scan through wifi signals for the currently set public ip addresses?

also.. imagine my switch is connected to the router of my ISP, and bridge mode is initiated, which means the NAT protocol.. and DHCP are shared right?

now of course the ISP router may or may not be connected to multiple switches, assuming it is, does the ISP's router have a NAT address table for each switch connected to it?

i'm assuming i could just run a full port scan to make sure of that, but will that work?

Comment: "_MAC addresses innately do not change right?_" It is very easy to change a MAC address in a host. "_Public IP addresses change, according to the ISP right?_" Most businesses have statically assigned public IP addresses. You mean a residential ISP, and residential networking is explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are you able to scan broadcasting APs for their public ip addresses?

No. Unless you manage to connect to the wifi network and successfully use it to connect to a service actually telling you your visible address you can't find out the WAN IP.

> ... a result of me recently discovering SHODAN ...

You know that SHODAN is fictional, don't you?

The rest of your questions are very much off-topic, sorry (and don't make too much sense). Hypothetical constructions with networks under your control are entirely off-topic.

Comment: oh!, shodan is fictional, wow, didn't even know that :D
thanks for the heads up